# Use `params` within `params`

Tags: r, r-markdown

In RMarkdown documents, is there a way to make parameters depend on other parameters within the YAML field `params`?

The following YAML header results in an error:

```yaml
---
params:
  years: !r 2020:2023
  period: !r max(params$years)
title: ""
date: ""
---
```